# python syntax error output

Tags: python

Please could you help me by fixing the error with my code. When I print last line I get a syntax error message:

```
import math


m_ = 900         # identifier for normal distribution mean   [mm]
s_d = 1          # identifier for normal distribution standard deviation [mm]

print "DISTRIBUTION OF A PLATE WIDTH:" " MEAN", "=",m_,"," "STD DEV", "=", s_d
print ""
print "Using functions from the math library ..."


# The probability density function(pdf) for a normal distribution with mean m_ and 
standard deviation s_d    
ftotal = 0
term = 0.0
count = 0
while abs(term) > 911:
    ftotal += term
    count += 1
    term = term * xx / float(count)


print "x"  "          " " f(x)" "           " " F(x)"
print "890" ""  (1 / ((s_d * (2 * math.pi) ** -0.5)) * math.exp((- (x - m_) ** 2) / (2 * (s_d) ** 2),   0.5 * (1 + math.erf((x - m_) / s_d * m.sqrt(2))
```

Comment: align the code in your while loop. It is not clear what your while loop has?

Comment: Also missing operator before `0.5` in `(2 * (s_d) ** 2)   0.5` from last line.

Comment: sorry, these are two separated formulas, but I do not know how to separate them correctly

Comment: Define x first. by `xx` do you mean `x*x`? In last line, at the end you have written `m.sqrt(2)` I think you mean `math.sqrt(2)`. Also put `,` after "890". And put matching braces in the last line.

Answer (score 3):

Define x before the while loop. From the last two lines where you have denoted x by 890 so I am guessing `x = 890`.

```
x = 890
#your while loop goes here

print "x"  "          " " f(x)" "           " " F(x)"
print "890" ,  (1 / ((s_d * (2 * math.pi) ** -0.5))) * math.exp((- (x - m_) ** 2) / (2 * (s_d) ** 2))  , 0.5 * (1 + math.erf((x - m_) / s_d * math.sqrt(2)))
```

I can't remember the exact formula but if the above expressions are correctly put, you won't get a syntax error.

Comment: If this answers your question, you can accept the answer by clicking on the tickmark just to the left of answer.